# mysql - alternative / efficient / optimized query

Tags: mysql

I want alternative / efficient / optimized query for following query:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `bartco_web_vms_studio`.`table_name` (
      `index` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `id1` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `id2` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL,
      `f3` TINYINT( 4 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY ( `index` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX id1_id2 ON tablename (id1, id2);
```

Number of rows = 7891

Update query:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET f3=1 
WHERE id1=1 AND id2='a' 
   OR id1=2 AND id2='b'
   OR id1=3 AND id2='c'
```

Basically I have to update a field's value based on 2 fields (id1, id2) values. These 2 fields can be in more than 1 pair.

Output from `EXPLAIN SELECT f3 FROM table_name WHERE ...`:

```
id -> 1,
select type -> SIMPLE,
table -> table_name,
type -> range,
possible_keys -> id1_id2,
key -> id1_id2,
key_len -> 261,
ref -> NULL,
rows -> 2,
Extra -> Using where
```

Thanks a lot for help

Regards

Comment: Do you have an index for id1, id2?

Comment: @InSane - good question, +1.  Just to expand on this, the ideal index includes both id1 and id2 in the one index.  Just wanted to state that as this is a beginner question.

Comment: You're aware that the provided query isn't going to pair the id1 & id2 values as you've declared -- right?  You need to use brackets for it to be evaluated properly.

Comment: @OMG AND is higher precendence than OR, so I don't think brackets are required.  That said, I always feel more comfortable putting them in - and a bracket around the entire set of OR'ed clauses protects against the only-too-easy adding of an additional clause to the end and getting "the wrong behaviour".

Comment: hi thanks all for replying. Yes i have index on rows (index = 5 contains id1 =1 and id2 = 'a'). Sorry @OMG Ponies I didn't understand what you r saying

Comment: Could you post the results of `EXPLAIN SELECT f3 FROM table_name WHERE id1=1 AND id2='a' OR id1=2 AND id2='b' OR id1=3 AND id2='c'`, please?

Comment: i got a table as follows: id -> 1, select type -> SIMPLE, table -> table_name, type -> ALL, possible_keys -> NULL, key -> NULL, key_len -> NULL, ref -> NULL, rows -> 9, Extra -> where

Comment: Interesting - no index is being used.  Could you try this again, but with just `WHERE id1=1 AND id2='a'` rather than the three OR'ed clauses, please?

Comment: How many rows are there in the table?  If there are only a handful (as it looks like there may be), MySQL will probably not use the index.

Comment: Same output. Just to be clear, there is index field in table that works as primary key

Comment: ya right now only 9 but later may be 90000

Comment: Your index on (id1, id2) covers this UPDATE - when you get more data in your table, the index _should_ be used - at the moment, I believe MySQL is deeming the index unnecessary - a table scan is more efficient than probing the index for this small table.

Comment: @Will A: mysql optimizer is very fickle about `OR`. So even on much data index can be ignored.

Comment: How big is your table in rows and how may rows have id = "1".

Comment: @zerkms - ah, well said.  I know MSSQL better than MySQL - OR is a pain there much of the time as well - although logically, OR does give the query optimizer a hard time.  :)

Comment: @user427969 - thanks for the create script - now, where's the index on (id1, id2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composite index `id1 + id2` and query

```
WHERE (id1, id2) IN ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'))
```

should help

Also, when you're even testing - add more rows into the table.

Since you're selecting 3 rows of 9 - mysql can decide never to use index at all.

**UPD**:

if nothing from our answers will help - you can always split your query to 3:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id1 .. AND id2 ..
UNION
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id1 .. AND id2 ..
...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is this query optimized? I mean i may have huge data in table so will this work faster or the one that i said ???

Comment: @user427969: yes, it should be better. Just fill your table with random data and check it.

Comment: This is certainly a better looking rephrasing of the original query - I'd expect the MySQL engine to cope well with either version.

Comment: I add 2160 rows and tested explain still i get the same ouput

Comment: @user427969: and what if you left only one pair? Also - update your question with **actual** table schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: @Will A - you told the index should be used when there is huge data. can u tell how ??? By finding index of id1 and id2 and then using it in query ????

Comment: Explain query gives same output with one pair or 2 or 3

Comment: @user427969: "how" - is the mysql optimizer business, not yours ;-) Give us actual schema please ;-)

Comment: For a table of only 2160 rows its almost certainly quicker to scan the whole table than use an index for this sort of query!

Comment: @James Anderson: why? it very depends on what and how many data he has in the row.

Comment: @James - if the 'sample' data its being tested on mostly matches vs. the IN(...), definitely.

Comment: @zerkms i didn't told "how" i just thought it would be useful. I updated my question

Comment: @user427969: you missed the first part of my answer. You need to create composite index `(id1, id2)`: `CREATE INDEX id1_id2 ON tablename (id1, id2);`

Comment: @user427969: An index _isn't_ a primary (or candidate) key - there is no requirement for the entries within an index to be unique.

Comment: @user427969: so? What explain says now?

Comment: @user427969: also you can check this answer as a correct answer ;-)

Comment: @user427969: is everything ok now?

Comment: ya fine. i m just testing. Thanks alot for help... Regards